# How to update existing deployment in AWS EKS Cluster?

Tags: amazon-eks

I have my application deployed in AWS EKS Cluster and now I want to update the deployment with the new image that I created from the recent GIT commit.

I did try to use:

`kubectl set image deployment/mydeploy mydeploy=ECR:2.0`

> error: unable to find container named "stag-simpleui-deployment"

I also tried:

`kubectl rolling-update mydeploy mydeploy.2.0 --image=ECR:2.0`

> Command "rolling-update" is deprecated, use "rollout" instead
>   Error from server (NotFound): replicationcontrollers "stag-simpleui-deployment" not found

It is confusing with so many articles say different ways, but none is working.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to crack it.  In below command line "mydeploy=" should be same as your image name in your "kubectl edit deployment mydeploy"

kubectl set image deployment/mydeploy mydeploy=ECR:2.0